# Can't change network to bridged: There are no unbridged host network adapter VMware 15

Tags: windows-10

The reference screenshots are in images 1-4. How can I solve the problem?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

---

[image: image 3]

---

[image: image 4]

Comment: Go to the Guest Settings with the machine off (not started). Change the Networking to Bridged there. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

- One possible problem could be that the vmnetbridge service is not running. You can check this in the services control panel or try to start it in with an elevated cmd with

  ```
  net start vmnetbridge
  ```
- You can also try to reset VMware's Virtual Network Editor by clicking on the Restore Defaults button. This might be needed after manually installing VMware's Bridge Protocol.
- Another problem could be an incompatible driver as VMware is known to have problems with some Intel drivers. Sometimes it helps to remove the corresponding driver and let windows assign a generic driver.
- Also, sometimes antivirus software leads to this problem. There are cases when uninstalling kasperky antivirus solved this issue, or configuring it in the Physical network card properties by unchecking the Kasperky Anti-Virus NDIS 6 Filter element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the error reporting is horrendous.  It turned out that the issue was that VCRuntime140.dll was missing.  I only found this out because I noticed that the VMWare USB arbitration service wasn't running.

When I manually ran the VMWare USB arbitration executable contained within C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\VMware\USB\vmware-usbarbitrator64.exe I received the error that VCRuntime140.dll was missing.  The problem is that the 'no unbridged adapters" problem is very non-specific.  After repairing the Microsoft C++ runtime redistributables and running the virtual network editor, all was well.